# AppScript for Google sheets to FILTER dropdown lists

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, dropdown, spreadsheet

I'm creating a spreadsheet in Google Sheets to work as an App to introduce some data in a database.

I have a problem creating a dropdown which list changes dynamically.
I'll try to explain it and here's the simplified version:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x2VwmnyiksitzeXQpGocBetef2GilvqIY8ar-6zJChc/edit#gid=307999969

I have a dropdown where I select between several options (in the example, between A, B and C).
Depending on this option, in column A there are different Parameters (using a FILTER function). On each option, I'd like to add a dropdown, which list depends on the result on the cell of the left (for B2, it should be A2). The list is included in the "Master" sheet.
Here, if I select Option A, then a list of Parameters appear: Equipment, Formulation and Time.
Right next to Equipment, there's a dropdown where I should be able to select between Eq1, Eq2 or Eq3.
I'd like to add a FILTER or a VLOOKUP kind of feature in the dropdown, so it checks the name of the parameter on the MASTER sheet and uses that list as the dropdown list.

I tried using ChatGPT but gave me some codes that never work. The closest was a code that changed the dropdown only when the cell on the left was manually changed, but never got it to change when the result of the FILTER function changed.

I can't create a dynamic table separately (and hidden) because the App has hundreds of this tables.

Do you have any idea of how to implement this?
Thank you

Comment: I would like to clarify that all of the options (like A, B, and C) in the example will result to three. Would that be correct?

Comment: You mean a list of three items? No, not always. In the master sheet I put examples of different lengths. In the real model there are up to 10 in some cases, but I'm simplifying it assuming that the solution can be applied to the real environment. Also, not every parameter has a drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

### RECOMMENDED SOLUTION

You may use this answer as a reference to what you'd like to accomplish.

##### OPTION 1

Using `Google Sheets Formulas`, you can do these steps in order to achieve what you'd like to do.

1. Set up a helper column in the `MASTER` sheet that would be dependent on your selections in `Sheet31`'s filter.

It would look like this:

[image: HELPER COLUMN]

### GOOGLE SHEET FORMULA

In cell `K1`:

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:I),"Select * where Col1 ='"&Sheet31!A2&"'")
```

In cell `K2`:

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:I),"Select * where Col1 ='"&Sheet31!A3&"'")
```

In cell `K3`:

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:I),"Select * where Col1 ='"&Sheet31!A4&"'")
```

This makes it dynamic, so all of the options in the table example would be selected.

2. Create a data validation dropdown that's pointed to the helper column you've created.

Something like this:

[image: DROPDOWN DATA VALIDATION]

In cell `B2`:

```
=MASTER!$L$1:$Z$1
```

In cell `B3`:

```
=MASTER!$L$2:$Z$2
```

In cell `B4`:

```
=MASTER!$L$3:$Z$3
```

> You can change the last part of the cell range depending on how many options you have.

### OUTPUT (WITH HELPER COLUMN IN ANOTHER WINDOW)

[image: OUTPUT1]

##### OPTION 2

Using Google Apps Script, you can utilize what you'd like to do using the [`onEdit(e)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger.

> I have also added some explanations of what the code does

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Initializes the trigger
  var value = e.value;
  // Gets your current active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // Gets the sheet named "MASTER"
  var masterSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MASTER");
  // Gets the sheet named "Sheet31"
  var sheet31 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet31");

  // Gets the ranges for the dropdown
  var dropdown1 = sheet31.getRange("B2");
  var dropdown2 = sheet31.getRange("B3");
  var dropdown3 = sheet31.getRange("B4");

  // Gets the ranges of the options for the dropdown
  // Option A
  var equipmentOptions = masterSheet.getRange(3, 1, 3);
  var formulationOptions = masterSheet.getRange(3, 2, 4);
  var timeOptions = masterSheet.getRange(3, 3, 3);

  // Option B
  var schedOptions = masterSheet.getRange(3, 4, 3);
  var templateOptions = masterSheet.getRange(3, 5, 2);
  var dayOptions = masterSheet.getRange(3, 6, 2);

  // Option C
  var areaOptions = masterSheet.getRange(3, 7, 3);
  var zoneOptions = masterSheet.getRange(3, 8, 2);
  var partOptions = masterSheet.getRange(3, 9, 4);

  // Initialization for the data validation
  var dropdownDataValidation = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation();

  // Sets the dropdown of data validation depending on the value
  if (value == "A") {
    dropdown1.setDataValidation(dropdownDataValidation.requireValueInRange(equipmentOptions));
    dropdown2.setDataValidation(dropdownDataValidation.requireValueInRange(formulationOptions));
    dropdown3.setDataValidation(dropdownDataValidation.requireValueInRange(timeOptions));
  } else if (value == "B") {
    dropdown1.setDataValidation(dropdownDataValidation.requireValueInRange(schedOptions));
    dropdown2.setDataValidation(dropdownDataValidation.requireValueInRange(templateOptions));
    dropdown3.setDataValidation(dropdownDataValidation.requireValueInRange(dayOptions));
  } else if (value == "C") {
    dropdown1.setDataValidation(dropdownDataValidation.requireValueInRange(areaOptions));
    dropdown2.setDataValidation(dropdownDataValidation.requireValueInRange(zoneOptions));
    dropdown3.setDataValidation(dropdownDataValidation.requireValueInRange(partOptions));
  }
}
```

### OUTPUT

[image: OUTPUT2]

### REFERENCES

##### OPTION 1

- [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)
- [QUERY function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [Create an in-cell dropdown list](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103)

##### OPTION 2

- [Class SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)
- [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)
- [Class DataValidation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation)
- [Class DataValidationBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder)

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions, and I'll be happy to help in any way I can!

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! This is wonderful.

A bit problems trying to implement this:
- The issue here is that the example is just a simplified version. The real version has hundreds of dropdowns (and not all parameters are dropdowns).
- Also, it has the additional problem that the real one has a script to add new columns (copying a template): every time a user needs to adds data (in a column), it needs to click a button to add a new column at the end, and this has to apply to this new dropdowns too.

Comment: So my idea was to use some kind of VLOOKUP function, where each dropdown would compare its parameter (left cell) with the master, and uses that as its list. No idea how to do that in a script, but it would be very easy to do if Google sheets accepted formulas as dropdown ranges.

Comment: I'll upload another document more similar to the final version soon; thank you for your help!

Comment: That's unfortunate, and I totally understand. I'll try to check the document you'll upload and see what can be done to it. However, what I'll most likely try to do is the first option. The helper column can be set in another sheet, so it won't affect the integrity of the data in the `MASTER` sheet, and you won't need to do anything to it. With it's help, if there are dropdowns that don't have any data, you can simply set an `IFERROR` in the `QUERY` so that it will show what you'd like it to reflect if there's nothing on it (by default, it shows up as `#N/A`).

Comment: As for the `Google sheets accepted formulas as dropdown ranges.` statement, I suggest submitting a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new) as it is the best way to have Google check on your concern.

Comment: Here you can see a more real example of what I'm trying to achieve:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eH8rhJXDlUHjyBCW9ZvlaPZ-Ekvcjihz--89v0RlP5g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: As you see there are several "boxes" vertically alignes, with a dropdown where you select the step you prefer. Depending on the step you select, you have a different list of parameters. Depending on these parameters, you can have either a field or a dropdown, which list should be chosen according to the "SUPERMASTER" sheet. The parameters can have unique names if that makes thing easier.
There's an appscript (not sure if that will work still) to create new columns on the right (copied from the first ones) to add new experiments.

Comment: There are a few more functionalities, but that's the essence of the problem, I think.

For the list of each parameter dropdown, I was planning to do a TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE) together with a LOOKUP of that name, so that the new items written will be added on the list to appear in the following dropdowns).

What do you think? Is is reasonable what I'm asking?
Thank you again!

Comment: I was able to review the spreadsheet you provided. What you'd like to accomplish would be hard without a helper in each of the parameters to serve as the option for the second dropdown. What I can recommend is to add a helper column next to each parameter in the `SUPERNEW` sheet and have it hidden so that your users won't see it, or just create a new sheet and create the helpers there so that the other sheet would just have the dropdowns. The script that you have can also get the ranges on the other sheet for the helpers to be copied over as well.

Comment: As for `I was planning to do a TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE) together with a LOOKUP of that name, so that the new items written will be added on the list to appear in the following dropdowns).` If this would work for you, go for it!

Comment: Thanks for your help!

What I'm struggling is to add a helper besides each parameter (and in each box), since the list for each dropdown may be quite extensive (there are for instance more than 80 formulations, etc).
Another problem is that not all parameters have dropdowns, and this way wouldn't work if in a specific row there should be a dropdown or not depending on the first selection.
It seems to be a very simple think to ask, and very complicated to implement.